# Having some trouble with Julia's conversion rules

Tags: julia

In the Julia documentation manual, it says the following [1]:

> When is convert called?
>
> The following language constructs call convert:
>
> - Assigning to an array converts to the array's element type.

[1] https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/conversion-and-promotion/#When-is-convert-called?-1

I've defined the following code:

```
julia> abstract type Element end

julia> abstract type Inline <: Element end

julia> struct Str <: Inline
           content::String
       end

julia> convert(::Type{Str}, e::String) = Str(e)
convert (generic function with 1 method)

julia> convert(::Type{Element}, e::String) = convert(Str, e)
convert (generic function with 2 methods)
```

I have `convert` defined for Julia type `String`. And converting to `Element` and converting to `Str` from an instance of type `String` works as expected. However, the following fails:

```
julia> convert(Str, "hi")
Str("hi")

julia> convert(Element, "hi")
Str("hi")

julia> arr = Element[]
0-element Array{Element,1}

julia> push!(arr, "hi")
ERROR: MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type String to an object of type Element
Closest candidates are:
  convert(::Type{T}, ::T) where T at essentials.jl:168
Stacktrace:
 [1] push!(::Array{Element,1}, ::String) at ./array.jl:866
 [2] top-level scope at REPL[25]:1

julia> arr = Str[]
0-element Array{Str,1}

julia> push!(arr, "hi")
ERROR: MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type String to an object of type Str
Closest candidates are:
  convert(::Type{T}, ::T) where T at essentials.jl:168
  Str(::String) at REPL[19]:2
  Str(::Any) at REPL[19]:2
Stacktrace:
 [1] push!(::Array{Str,1}, ::String) at ./array.jl:866
 [2] top-level scope at REPL[27]:1

julia>
```

Can someone explain why the above fails? And how, if it is possible to do so, prevent it from failing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the main hint of your code was this line:
    convert (generic function with 1 method)
that means that the `convert` function has only one definition (your definition), so something was wrong. when Julia uses `convert`, it actually calls `Base.convert`. so, overloading the proper method:

```
Base.convert(::Type{Str}, e::String) = Str(e)
Base.convert(::Type{Element}, e::String) = convert(Str, e)
```

worked as expected with your code. 
In a nutshell, your code was right, you just were overloading the wrong convert (add always `Base.method` when working with Julia core functions)